# How to send raw text with xmlhttp request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send a `textarea` field's text to a PHP file using ajax, the text contains HTML characters and should not be encoded.

Using `FormData` it works perfectly however it's not supported in ie 9 and older versions! I tried to send the data as `string` by setting the `requestHeader` to `text/plain;charset=UTF-8;` or `multipart/form-data` but it didn't work!
the code i'm using is:

```
var string = '<td clas="tdClass">some text<?php echo $contents; ?></td>';

var data = new FormData();
data.append("data" , string);
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xhr.open( 'post', '/path/to/php', true );
xhr.send(data);
```

what's an alternative way to do this in IE 9?

Comment: I love how you didn't check for FormData but checked for XMLHttpRequest, also what are html characters? do you mean html tags? what kind of encoding you want to avoid?

Comment: The text contains characters like `< > ' " & ? . `, i need the text to be sent as it is!

Comment: The value has to be encoded, in case it contains form field delimiters. But the API for retrieving form fields in the server code should decode it and return the original string. If you're not using an API, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: can it not be acheived by setting `headerRequest` `content-type`/`content-description`/`content-transfer-encoding`/`boundary`? i'm reading some articles related to this but it's very complicated and confusing, i'm not sure how to do it or whether it'll work or not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be done by modifying `headerRequest` and `data` like this:

```
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

if(typeof(FormData) == 'undefined'){
    var boundary = '---------------------------' + (new Date).getTime(),//boundary is used to specify the encapsulation boundary of a parameter
        data = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
        data += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"\r\n\r\n';//here we specify the name of the parameter name (data) sent to the server which can be retrieved by $_POST['data']
        data += string + "\r\n";
        data += "--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
    xhr.open( 'post', 'writeCode.php', true );
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
}else{
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("data", string);
    xhr.open( 'post', 'writeCode.php', true );
}
xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: wow this is exactly what i was looking for, it worked in all browsers even IE 7 :), thank you very much

Comment: Using multipart/form-data here is **completely** unnecessary, and massively overcomplicated.  The same effect could be accomplished much more easily using a regular POST (i.e. application/x-www-form-urlencoded).  All the OP really wants is for his string to be delivered to PHP unaltered.

Answer (score 3):

If using `FormData` works correctly for you, then in situations where you can't use it, actually all you need to do is to replace your last line with:

```
xhr.send("data="+encodeURIComponent(string));
```

I think the other answerers were confused by your asking that the text "not be encoded".  Form data is generally encoded for sending over HTTP, but then *decoded* by PHP when it arrives at the server, *entirely transparently*:  you get *exactly the original text back*, no matter what special characters it might contain.  (Assuming you interpret the PHP string as UTF-8).

So, following your example, if your PHP file contained:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

Then the contents of the PHP `$data` variable would be the string `'<td clas="tdClass">some text<?php echo $contents; ?></td>'`.  This is the same as if you'd used the `FormData` method.

Answer (score 0):

Since, well, it appears to be pretty simple after all. Here is some more samples.

Just post random text

```js
// just text
var dest = "http://requestb.in/qwb9y3qw";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", dest, true);

var myText = "foobar";
xhr.send(myText);
```

Post a JSON object

```js
// post json
var dest = "http://requestb.in/1908jrv1";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", dest, true);

var myObject = {};
myObject.prop1 = "foo";
myObject.prop2 = "bar";
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```