# POST form data without = in payload

Tags: javascript, forms, http-post

Is it possible to perform a HTTP POST using a form and not getting = in the payload?

I want to just send a string directly because the API doesn't support data as query string parameter, but expect the body to contain the data I'm posting.

So instead of something like:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://somewhere/">
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="value" />
</form>
```

that would produce the HTTP POST payload body: '`key=value`'

I want to HTTP POST a form with payload: '`value`'

It's easy to do with CORS and XHR, but I don't really control this service and would like to do the POST without setting up a proxy in the middle with CORS. So is this even possible to with a `<form>`?

Comment: Using a regular form gets you past the same origin policy, but you have to be clearer on what you want to send, a POST request consists of keys and values, if you just want to send `value` you could probably try with an element having the name `value` and no value, but that would send `value=` which is probably as close as you'll get

Comment: Maybe this will work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15849693/451969 (Nevermind, now I see that you're trying to do with a form only, which I don't *think* is possible.) [(And there's this.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6665569/451969)

Comment: You should be able to send requests with ajax, you just can't receive the result, not that it's clear how one would do that with a form submit either ?

Comment: It should be `method="post"` instead of `action="post"`